# Photoshop: How to know current size of drawn shape when selecting contained shape layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I use *Rectangle tool*, *Rounded Rectangle Tool* ... to draw a shape. After that, I move to another layer then go back to nearly created shape layer.

My question is: How can I know current size of drawn shape ? I have press `Command + T` to open *transform tool* but still no see any information here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `Info` tab, while you are still in `Free Transform` mode:

[image: info]

Access it here:

[image: mwnu]

Starting at the upper-left section and moving clockwise, the information displayed is:

- Color
- Transformation
- Size
- Position